# How to run docker-compose against docker swarm (without docker-machine)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I have managed to manually set up a docker swarm (e.g.: without using docker-machine) following [the official tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/swarm/install-manual/)

I am able to run containers on the swarm successfully using docker engine:

```
docker -H :4000 run redis
```

I would like to use docker-compose to run containers on the swarm, however I cannot seem to get this right.

The first thing I had to work out was how to get compose to talk on port `:4000`. I achieved this by specifying: `export DOCKER_HOST=":4000"`.

However, now, when I run docker-compose I get the following error:

```
$docker-compose up
Creating network "root_default" with the default driver
ERROR: Error response from daemon: failed to parse pool request for address space "GlobalDefault" pool "" subpool "": cannot find address space GlobalDefault (most likely the backing datastore is not configured)
```

It feels like this issue has to do with either TLS or network, but I'm pretty stumped as to how to fix it, or even how to go about investigating it further.

I'm using Docker engine: 1.10, Compose 1.6. Swarm:latest

In case it's useful, here is my docker info:

```
$docker -H :4000 info
Containers: 7
 Running: 5
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 2
Images: 7
Server Version: swarm/1.2.0
Role: primary
Strategy: spread
Filters: health, port, dependency, affinity, constraint
Nodes: 2
 node02: 10.129.5.211:2375
  └ Status: Healthy
  └ Containers: 3
  └ Reserved CPUs: 0 / 2
  └ Reserved Memory: 0 B / 2.053 GiB
  └ Labels: executiondriver=, kernelversion=3.13.0-79-generic, operatingsystem=Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS, storagedriver=aufs
  └ Error: (none)
  └ UpdatedAt: 2016-04-15T08:28:20Z
  └ ServerVersion: 1.11.0
 node03: 10.129.6.21:2375
  └ Status: Healthy
  └ Containers: 4
  └ Reserved CPUs: 0 / 2
  └ Reserved Memory: 0 B / 2.053 GiB
  └ Labels: executiondriver=, kernelversion=3.13.0-79-generic, operatingsystem=Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS, storagedriver=aufs
  └ Error: (none)
  └ UpdatedAt: 2016-04-15T08:28:43Z
  └ ServerVersion: 1.11.0
Plugins: 
 Volume: 
 Network: 
Kernel Version: 3.13.0-79-generic
Operating System: linux
Architecture: amd64
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 4.105 GiB
Name: b156985db557
Docker Root Dir: 
Debug mode (client): false
Debug mode (server): false
WARNING: No kernel memory limit support
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Docker 1.10, Docker Swarm, Docker Compose on our production.

I have met the same issue in the past. And I solved it by steps as below:

Step 1: `export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://localhost:4000`

Step 2: Verify Docker Swarm by command `docker info` (without -H). If it not OK, make sure that Swarm Manager is working your host.

Step 3: If Step 2 is OK. Run your application on Docker Compose `docker-compose up`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and found the answer here: https://groups.google.com/a/weave.works/forum/m/#!topic/weave-users/Mf6fv9OEd-E

What fixed it was:

> To make it work with docker-compose 2, you should add:
>
> ```
> network_mode: "bridge"
> ```
>
> to all service definitions.

Answer (score -1):

to remove the above error, you need to run docker deamon on every node like this

docker run -d -p 4000:4000 swarm manage -H :4000 --replication --advertise 192.168.56.103:4000 consul://192.168.56.101:8500

Comment: Hi Shuja. I think I am already doing that? (well on the master nodes at least) - could you explain what in particular about that command fixes the problem above?

Comment: @toast38coza The error suggests the Docker Engine daemon isn't configured to work against a discovery service. The suggestion above will fix it

Comment: I don't think that's the issue .. the exact command I'm running for the swarm masters is: `docker run -d -p 4000:4000 swarm manage -H :4000 --replication --advertise <own_ip>:4000 consul://<consul_ip:8500`